# ChangeConflictException when submitting LINQ entity with XML field

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I have a business object type representing customers which, when its `.Save()` method is called, attempts to retrieve (using LINQ) a matching entity from the database based on the object's ID property. If it **does not** find a matching entity, it creates a new one; if it **does** find a matching entity it updates that entity's properties and calls `[my datacontext].SubmitChanges()`.

That last part is the problem. Much of the data for a user is stored in an XML field in the database, named `content_xml`. There is a bug in the code which is failing to retrieve two of those data items ("coordinates" and "sales_groups") when constructing the business object, and so when the `.Save()` method goes to update the entity, the XML it's sending is missing those elements.

For some reason this is throwing a ChangeConflictException, stating that "1 of 12" updates failed. In order to identify what was causing the problem, I used the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx to extract information about the change conflict.

From that, I see that `[my datacontext].ChangeConflicts` contains a single `ObjectChangeConflict`, which itself contains a single `MemberChangeConflict` representing the XML field.

The part I do not understand is that when checking the values of `currVal`, `origVal` and `databaseVal`, I see that XML data held in `currVal` is what I would expect based on the bug (it's missing the two elements), and the XML for `origVal` and `databaseVal` are identical. That shouldn't cause a conflict, should it?

Even more strange is that when I manually correct the bug by providing the correct (according to the database) values for the missing elements, just before the `.SubmitChanges()` call, it *still* causes a conflict, even though the XML from all three (`currVal`, `origVal` and `databaseVal`) all now look identical.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the conflict?

**Edit:**

OK, this is a bit of a surprise, but even if I *never set the `content_xml` property value* of the retrieved entity before submitting changes, I still get a conflict on the XML field.

Answer (score 0):

I would *guess* that the change conflict stems from L2S comparing old vs new value in an incorrect way for your xml field.

A possible workaround for this is to add a timestamp or rowversion column to the table and updating the L2S model. If a table contain rowversion/timestamp, *only* that column will be used for detecting change conflicts...

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to give L2S a new method for comparing values for concurrency issues, other than modifying the database? Something like overriding the .Equals() implementation on ordinary type, perhaps?

Comment: Actually, now that I have continued to look into this, the underlying database table DOES have a timestamp field (I didn't build the datacontext, so hadn't realised this until just now).

Comment: The concurrency comparison is usually part of the update statement sent to the DB, so no easy way to override. However, a next step would be to use a profiler to check what it hits the db with...   ...that may reveal what is going wrong.